# jsf 2.0 and welcome-files

Tags: jsf-2

I have some problems with the default URL that jsf shows:

The url is displayed like this:

www.URL.com/PROYECT_NAME/

And I want something like this

www.URL.com/PROYECT_NAME/home

I sent up the welcome file like this.

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file >faces/views/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So what I really want is that when jsf shows the welcome file show and url like this www.URL.com/PROYECT_NAME/home or the complete route faces/views/home.xhtml.

I know is a dumb question but Im stock in it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve that using a filter-based servlet extension like [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

It is simple to use, has good documentation and examples, but to illustrate your case you could do something like this:

- Download prettyfaces.jar and add to your classpath. Usually `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.
- Add a pretty-config.xml file containing the URL mappings to the `/WEB-INF` folder.

Example of pretty-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.3 http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.3.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="home">
        <pattern value="/home" />
        <view-id value="/home.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

To redirect to this mapping from a controller you should use a string like `pretty:` + `url-mapping-id`.

Example of controller bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class HomeBean
{
    public String goHome()
    {
        return "pretty:home";
    }
}
```

That's it. Whenever you fire a request, if PrettyFaces filter finds the url mapping pattern `/home` it will display the view id `home.xhtml` but keep the URL as `/home`. Pretty.

Also, as a suggestion, for your `welcome-file-list` you could add only `index.html`.

Example of web.xml welcome-file-list tag:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And add an index.html file like this to your application root folder.

Example of index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>My Application</title>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/myapplication/home" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Loading...</h3>
        </body>
    </html>
```

By doing this, whenever someone requests your application it will get a fast loading page and will be redirected to `/home`.

I hope it helps.